# How to enable alternative log in sessions (e.g. Unity 2D or others) in Trusty?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, 14.04, unity-2d, gnome-session

I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS to 14.04 LTS on an i386 system (Dell Optiplex 740, with an integrated nvidia quadro NVS 210S chipset).

The upgrade proceeded smoothly without any problem.

In 12.04 I had the possibility of enabling the 2D Unity shell (or gnome-classic shells, and other alternatives) from the main log in screen.

However, after upgrading to 14.04 I see no way to specify my default log in session (there is no icon available to open a menu in the log in screen).

How can I enable alternative sessions in 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : http://glx-dock.org/

It allows you to choose your session GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Unity-2d is not supported anymore ([since 12.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29#Unity_2Dhttp://en.wikipedia.or)) and I don't think the gnome classic shell is supported either.

You can install other alternatives eg. ubuntu-gnome, lubuntu (lxde), xubuntu (xfce), kubuntu (kde) alongside unity (you'll be able to choose in the login screen) by eg. `apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`. Just note **before you try that** maybe read up a bit and even play with it in a virtual machine because it is not a very simple process to remove it completely again. Maybe you can back up which packages you had before you try any of these then you should be able to revert your system again if needed.